# How to improve phonegap SQLite performance, and what are the differences between Storage API and SQLite plugins

Tags: performance, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phonegap to access a database on the device to perform some inserts, however I'm getting less than ideal performance.

Questions:

1. I see that there are some SQLite plugins for phonegap out there, do these have better performance comparing with the [default Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)?
2. what are the best/most used SQLite plugins for all three major platforms? (android, ios, wp)
3. how do I improve phonegap SQLite performance?

the two most important performance improvement that I can do if I were to interact with SQLite directly according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite) seems to be to

- perform the inserts in a transaction
- prepare the insert statement

all my insert happened in one transaction, but how would I make the second item happen? is it possible with the Storage API?

Thanks.

Comment: Bump, can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 0):

Although this posting isn't directly aimed at Cordova based applications, there might be some useful information in this posting. I do both native and Cordova based mobile programming and I find that SQLite is generally the same animal regardless of OS, Hardware or development platform. Hope this helps
 
 
[Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite)

Comment: Sorry I was speaking specifically about performance tweaks. I use the com.phonegap.plugins.sqlite solution, and haven't found any reason to use anything else yet...